# VBA Loop cut/paste/skip

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Very new to VBA and macros.  Looking to build a macro that will cut the items in G2:H2, paste them in I2:J2, skip to the next even numbered row, cut those items (G4:H4), paste those into I4:J4, and so-on until the end of the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has roughly 11200 rows to sort through. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

```
Sub TotalMove()
'
' TotalMove Macro

a = 2
g = Sheet17.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For a = 2 To g Step 2

    Range("G2:H2").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("I2:J2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
  
Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: So this is a straight forward loop where your `Step = 2`. How to loop is well documented here,* and in many other places*. In short, there are enough resources out there to get you started on this. Do the research, take a stab at writing this yourself, and then come back here when you have a specific question/issue with your attempt. Be sure to share your code and issue :)

Comment: @urdearboy thanks for responding. Here is my current code. As of now, it is stuck looping through the original two cellsSub TotalMove()
'
' TotalMove Macro

a = 2
g = Sheet17.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For a = 2 To g Step 2

    Range("G2:H2").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("I2:J2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
  
Next a

End Sub

Comment: You are probably better off making a new post. Make sure to add your code to the question, not in the comments. Have you browsed this site for answers? If so you will probably notice that all the questions have code in the post, not the comment...

Comment: @urdearboy I really appreciate you trying to help me here. I just edited the question, but looks like moderators have closed the question and I am now unable to post a new one for 3 days. Any help here is truly appreciated.

Comment: I voted to re-open but now waiting on others. Always share your code so this doesnt happen - otherwise you are asking people to just do your work for you. You are also closer than you think so it would be a waste of everyones time to start from nothing

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, was just a case of using your row number in the loop.

I made the variable names obvious for demo, set values rather than copy-paste, and specified the sheet in ranges.

```
Sub TotalMove()

With Sheet17
    StartRow = 2
    EndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For CurrentRow = StartRow To EndRow Step 2
        .Range("I" & CurrentRow & ":J" & CurrentRow) = .Range("G" & CurrentRow & ":H" & CurrentRow).Value
        .Range("G" & CurrentRow & ":H" & CurrentRow).Clear
    Next CurrentRow
End With

End Sub
```